# How to create "buy now" button which should redirects to onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I am new to magento, using Magento 1.9. with custom theme. I succesfully created buy now button on `addtocart.phtml` by the following codes:

```
<button type="button" title="Buy Now" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setcheckoutLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
    <span><span>Buy Now</span></span>
</button>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
```

---

But am confused in **where to paste below javascripts on my `view.phtml`?** can any one say exactly next to which function or step number, I should paste these scripts?

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: location,
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.your-site.com/checkout/onepage/";
        }
    });
</script>
```

I planned to have 2 buttons,without disturbing eachothers:When someone clicks:

1. **Buynow button** which should redirect to `checkout/onepage`
2. **Add to cart button** should do its default `checkout/cart`

Thanks in advance. Any suggestions are very welcome! :)

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do

Comment: I need 'Buynow' button along with Add to cart button for each product

Answer (score 3):

The add to cart request is a GET request that among other params, it can contain a **uenc** param with can hold a base64 encoded return URL. The user is redirected to that URL upon return from add to cart.

You can simply create a new button that you add anywhere on the page, that on click will do a GET request to a URL like `https://example.com/checkout/cart/add/product/XYZ/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9jaGVja291dC9vbmVwYWdlCg==/` where *aHR0cHM6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9jaGVja291dC9vbmVwYWdlCg==* is base64 encoded *https://example.com/checkout/onepage*

Comment: What code did you use?

Comment: edited my question,above is my codes

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax({
    type:”GET”,
    url:location,
    success:function(data){
        window.location.href = “http://www.your-site.com/checkout/onepage/”;
    }
});
</script>
```

Put this code in your view.phtml after the closing  tag.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. It makes a random AJAX request right after you open the page and then redirects to the checkout.