# Magento 1.9 How to add buy now button in product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart

I am using magento 1.9, I want to add BUY NOW button on product details page, Buy now button redirect to checkout page. I tried many solution already solved in this forum, But all the solutions are BUY NOW button redirect to cart page only. Here I was list outed already tried solutions are,

1. [Solution1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/how-to-create-and-add-buy-now-button-along-with-add-to-cart-button-on-each-pro)
2. [Solution2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109145/hot-to-add-buy-now-button-on-product-page-which-will-take-customer-to-checkout-p)
3. [Solution3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/how-to-create-and-add-buy-now-button-along-with-add-to-cart-button-on-each-pro/94387#94387)
4. [Solution4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23562/how-to-add-buy-now-button-url)
5. [Solution5](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76439/how-to-create-buy-now-button-which-should-redirects-to-onepage-checkout)

Answer (score 9):

First, change **Add to Cart** Button to **Buy Now**.

Then add a hidden input field to the ***#product_addtocart_form*** form. Name should be ***return_url*** and its value should be `<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>"`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>" name="return_url" />
```

If you want ***both Add to Cart and Buy now***, add the **buy now** button to `addtoCart.phtml`

```
<button type="button" 
        title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>"
        class="button btn-cart" 
        onclick="productBuyNowForm.submit(this)">
    <span><span>Buynow</span></span>
</button>
```

On that buttons onlick event, a custom `VarienForm` is used, `productBuyNowForm.submit(this)`, which will submit this form and redirect to checkout onepage.

**To define this custom form, add the following JavaScript code at view.phtml**

```
var productBuyNowForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
productBuyNowForm.submit = function (button, url) {
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;

        if (url) {
            form.action = url;
        }

        /* add return Url */
        var inputreturn= document.createElement("input");
        inputreturn.type = "hidden";
        inputreturn.name = "return_url";
        inputreturn.value = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>";
        document.getElementById('product_addtocart_form').appendChild(inputreturn);
        /* add return Url */
        // Append a line break 
        var e = null;
        try {
            this.form.submit();
        } catch (e) {
        }
        this.form.action = oldUrl;
        if (e) {
            throw e;
        }

        if (button && button != 'undefined') {
            button.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}.bind(productBuyNowForm);
```

Comment: Sir thanks for your answer, I tried your solution. First i was hide my add to cart button and create new Buy now button in addtocart.phtml then added needed code from your solution. Output it display a button with out any action. Again i was enable add to cart button then i will check, Buy now button takes no action, Add to cart button goes to check out page, but i can't enter any data in one page checkout. All the sections are empty or can't show the content area just show the heading only.

Comment: please check now,it was a syntax issue

Comment: @AmitBera, Amit. Great bro. i just tried your answer. and it is working properly. +1 for your answer from me.  But, when i clicked on buynow button , i am getting the error on popup, then i clciked on ok then its going to checkout. please check once.

Comment: @AmitBera, i tried your answer. its working perfectly. but, when i clicked on buynow button it shows one form key error on popup. plz help me to clear that.   https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/f6xEFM_0IFNH7Dzv609c74bNg-Z9PgLMb8raWkFar9ND39q_KKlMjJkPAQRQQpGuuLnIJw=s500

Comment: Really strange .. may be you need  page refresh.Seems issue  session

Comment: But i implimented the code as it is of your code

Comment: ha ha , You should be check my code  and an alert is there `alert(form.action);` need to remove it