# Unwanted form_key popup

Tags: magento-1.8, addtocart, form-key

So I just added a Buy Now button in my store using this previously answered question: [Magento 1.9 How to add buy now button in product page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123072/magento-1-9-how-to-add-buy-now-button-in-product-page)

Everything works fine, however I'm getting a pop up after pressing the Buy Now button.

It reads:

```
www.mystore.net says: https://www.mystore.net/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGI4ZWxtYXJrZXQubmV0L3dhbmQuaHRtbA,,/product/8/form_key/qPvLAuhxmDQklkqt/
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/av4aq.png

Is there anyway to just bypass it throwing this message?

Javascript added to app/design/frontend/ultimo/pixel/template/catalog/product/view.pthml:

```
var productBuyNowForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
productBuyNowForm.submit = function (button, url) {
  if (this.validator.validate()) {
    var form = this.form;
    var oldUrl = form.action;
    alert(form.action);
    if (url) {
        form.action = url;
    }

    /* add return Url */
    var inputreturn= document.createElement("input");
    inputreturn.type = "hidden";
    inputreturn.name = "return_url";
    inputreturn.value = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>";
        document.getElementById('product_addtocart_form').appendChild(inputreturn);
    /* add return Url */
    // Append a line break 
    var e = null;
    try {
        this.form.submit();
    } catch (e) {
    }
    this.form.action = oldUrl;
    if (e) {
        throw e;
    }

    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
        button.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}.bind(productBuyNowForm);
```

Button added to app/design/frontend/ultimo/pixel/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml:

```
<button type="button" 
    title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>"
    class="button btn-cart" 
    onclick="productBuyNowForm.submit(this)">
 <span><span>Buynow</span></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
alert(form.action);
```

It was probably added for debugging and then forgotten to remove.

**Tip:** Use `console.log` for debug output to print to the browser console instead of  `alert`

**Pro Tip:** Every major browser comes with a JavaScript debugger where you can set breakpoints and inspect variables. This is even better than adding debug output to your code.